# No contract for a month

Tags: software-industry, contracts

In my country is a very common situation for technology companies to require a "training period" for their new *recently graduated* employees, in the company I am in this one lasts for 9 months (though they make the contract for a year to give the next team a transition time with the "old guys"). The situation is that this contract ended on February, no one at the company has made any contact with us, though our boss (a 3rd party, outsourcing) has talked with the company and ensured us another year of work (not training here), from which they should raise our salaries and give us all the benefits of a proper work contract (health insurance, etc.).

My boss has had yet another talk with the person in charge of giving us the contracts, he responded that he needs to sync with another C-level member of the company, this happened like 10 days ago.

What are the best options here?

Answer (score 3):

So if I understood correctly you were in a training period and your contract of 1 year ended but they didn't made any contact with you to renew your contract and they still consider you an `intern`. From my point of view, I think you should start writing your resume and look for other jobs. The training period contract doesn't oblige the company to pay any fees or something in case they fire you. I've seen some similar cases where companies are using this "training" method to get candidates to work for a project, once the project is done they can end the contract at any time without any law difficulties since it's just a training and you have to `prove` yourself before they recruit can you.

With a training contract or without is the same thing as I see things, since you can lose your job at any time using the argument "Not suitable for the position"

In my country, lots of companies use the same thing, but the duration of a training contract cannot exceed 6 months, after this period, they either sign an official employement contract with you or they can choose to let you go.

This is just my point of view based on some experiences that I've seen.

I wish you luck in you job.

Comment: I didn't mention that the training contract states that _if the company decides to hire me_ I have to stay for a given number of years, or otherwise pay a high sum of money. Since this contract ended a month ago, is this clause still valid?

Comment: Your contract lasts 1 year, as far as I know it's now `INVALID` and you have no obligation towards the company, when companies hire someone they add this term in the contract to make sure that their new recruits won't leave early. You said yourself that the contract ended a month ago, that means that you are no longer considered an employee in their company and you can be one only if they renew your contract.

Answer (score 2):

Are you still getting paid for the work you do?  If you're still getting paid for the work you do... well, contractual instability happens, and the issue is being handled at levels above you.  The uncertainty is unpleasant, but there's not a lot you can do about it.  For now, just keep working and keep getting paid.

At the same time, if I'm reading this right, it's not a particularly good sign as far as long-term stability of your position, and you're not getting paid as much as you should be.  That means that you should be sharpening up your resume and looking for another position.  It's *possible* that your current workplace will give you another contract at some point, but by no means guaranteed.

Comment: Yes, I'm still being paid my training salary.

Answer (score 2):

If C-Level members of the company need to "sync", it's a budget issue - Either they didn't budget for your positions this year, or the company has found itself short of cash they thought they'd have. Either way, it suggests your employment there isn't likely to be very reliable, even if you're a high performer. You should consider looking elsewhere, especially because having a year's experience under your belt makes you a much more viable candidate.